# Microsoft Sql Server multiple aggreate functions using Pivot

Tags: sql-server, pivot

I have the data like this

```
select * from age;

Payor   Description  ID    Amount
---------------------------------
Medical    S1        101    200
Medical    s1        102    100
Medical    S2        201    400
Medical    S2        202    450
Medical    S3        301    500
```

I need the data in the following format, first 3 columns gives total amount and last 3 columns give distinct count of Id's

```
Payor   S1  S2  S3  S1_Count S2_Cnt S3_cnt 
-------------------------------------------
Medical 300 850 500   2        2      1
```

Or I am fine in displaying the same data in different multiple lines

```
Payor   s1  s2  s3
--------------------
Medical 300 850 500
Medical  2   2   1
```

One aggregate function gives sum of the amount and another aggregate function gives distinct count of id's

I have tried to use Pivot but I couldn't able to figure out how to use two aggregate functions in single SQL command. When I use `count(distinct ID)` it is throwing an error right away not sure what mistake I am doing.

Using the following code I could able to get the first 3columns s1,s2,s3 which are the sum of amount for that particular payor.

```
SELECT 
    [payor], [s1], [s2], [s3]            
FROM   
    (SELECT 
         [payor], des, amount 
     FROM age) AS age1 ---- from age table
PIVOT 
    (SUM(amount) FOR des IN ([s1], [s2], [s3] ) AS t2; --- sum
```

Can anyone help me to get the proper format I am looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with UNION:

```
Select payor, S1, S2, S3
FROM
(
Select payor, Description, count(ID) CountVal, 1 AS Orderby from table
group by payor, Description) z
PIVOT
(
MAX(CountVal) FOR Description IN ([S1], [S2], [S3])
) x

UNION

Select payor, S1, S2, S3
FROM
(
Select payor, Description, SUM(Amount) SumVal, 0 AS Orderby from table
group by payor, Description) z
PIVOT
(
MAX(SumVal) FOR Description IN ([S1], [S2], [S3])
) x
```

OUTPUT:

```
payor       S1      S2      S3
-------------------------------
Medical     2       2       1
Medical     300     850     500
```

Using Simple CASE WHEN:

```
SELECT
Payor,
S1 = SUM (case when Description = 'S1' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END),
S2 = SUM (case when Description = 'S2' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END),
S3 = SUM (case when Description = 'S3' THEN Amount ELSE 0 END),
S1_Cnt = COUNT (case when Description = 'S1' THEN ID ELSE NULL END),
S2_Cnt = COUNT (case when Description = 'S2' THEN ID ELSE NULL END),
S3_Cnt = COUNT (case when Description = 'S3' THEN ID ELSE NULL END)
FROM table
GROUP BY Payor
```

OUTPUT:

```
Payor   S1      S2      S3  S1_Cnt      S2_Cnt      S3_Cnt
-----------------------------------------------------------
Medical 300     850     500    2         2            1
```

Comment: Thank you so much Sir, I have tried  using pivot union it doubled my execution time however case statement worked well for me.